# Why do I have blank page when serving VueJS 3 build with ExpressJS?

Tags: express, vuejs3

I have a web application, coded with VueJS 3, that runs well with `npm run serve` and `npm run build; npx serve -s dist`.

My problem is that, when serving the build files with ExpressJS and my NodeJS application, I can see in my browser that I successfuly downloaded all the required elements, but the only thing I get is a blank page, with no error.

I expect to see my application working, as it does with `serve`, or `npm run serve`. I launch my NodeJS application with `npm run dev`. Is it a problem?

Comment: What would be the use-case for such? Also, some code is welcome here if you want some help.

Comment: The use-case is that I have a VueJS application and a NodeJS API. I would like to serve the all services with one server instead of 2.

Also, I have quite no idea of what code to share... I have actually zero idea why this would not work.

Comment: Why do you want to have both of them in the same place at all? Send one to Heroku and the other to Netlify/Vercel. No benefit to having them in the same place, more drawbacks tbh.

Comment: I do not understand why it would be better. I do not even know those platforms, nor why I would chose one over the other.

Comment: Eh, please give me more material on what you plan to do overall, will be faster to interact. Planning to host it on OVH or some other french provider? I proposed Heroku because it's a well-known great platform for Node apps. While Netlify/Vercel is a perfect place for any SPA app like Vue, free and super powerful.

Comment: I aim to develop 1 API with NodeJS and 2 different applications with VueJS. I want one VueJS app to be for administration purposes and the other one for clients. Instead of having 3 different services, which I do have today, in development, I would like to have everything in one place, as it seems to make more sense, at first look.

For production, I want to minimize cost, and aim to put everything on an Azure Web App instance.

Comment: I recommend decoupling them, especially if you're planning to have an API + frontends plugged into it. Paying for a Node API will be mandatory, while Vue apps are static and can be hosted for free. You will have less load on your backend not bothering to serve the Vue app, especially if you use it as API only. Because if you have an Nginx/Apache server, it will be busy serving while a CDN serving your static files will be far better/faster/less complex to handle in the long run. Cost-wise, Azure is more complex but totally fine if you want to have something cheap indeed.

Comment: Ok, I will follow your guidance and thank you for that and your time.

Would you excuse me if I do not put your comments as answer? I consider the initial question not to be answered and just plan on deleting it.

Comment: No point into deleting it: it can help other people read the comments in a future. It is rarely a good idea to delete something on StackOverflow tbh.